# Small act for improving site stats

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

It can be observed from the [area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) that we are lagging in answers.

And we can see that answers for many questions can be easily answered by some users. But, the users mayn't get time to post the answers or by several other reasons, the questions remain unanswered.

In this context, I want to give a hack that can improve the site stats. The hack is that if an user knows about the scripture in which the answer is present, then please **comment the link of the scripture**, either large or small (size of scripture). Some other user,  who has time, can read the scripture from the link and can answer the question afterwards.

What are your opinions on this?

Comment: There’s even lack of voting on our site which discourages people from posting Qs or As

Comment: Strange enough, the voting works fine on meta :P

Comment: One reason we lag in answers is because some of the questions do not even meet the threshold, and ought to be closed or deleted

Comment: I don't focus much on Area51 states now becuse that criteria is not followed today for evaluation I think. Secondly, It is not always easy to answer questions on sites like ours. There should be separate criteria for technical and non technical sites on Area51.

Comment: Nice.. @Pandya hoping that our site will get graduated quickly...

Answer (score 10):

Your idea is good but I don't think that it is needed.

The Islam.SE site has been graduated. You can see the stats that the site had at the end of its Beta stage from [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam).

To compare:

| [Hinduism.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) | [Islam.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) |
| --- | --- |
| **7.4 questions per day** | 5.1 questions per day |
| 75% answered questions | **87% answered questions** |
| 1.6 answer ratio | **1.8 answer ratio** |
| **10k+ visits/day** | 8k+ visits/day |
| **642 avid users** | 370 avid users |

So, strictly speaking, they fell short in various departments (like we are doing now) but that did not stop them from getting graduated.

We can also get graduated after some more time may be?

Comment: Islam Stack Exchange graduated on the basis of site age, not on Area51 stats. Visit [The 29 Beta sites that are 7+ years old no longer have the "Beta" label!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/260388) for more information

Comment: Yes I have seen that MSE post @Pandya

Comment: Despite Islam.SE being old enough to graduate based on the basis of age, it still had only half as many avid users, and not as many visits/day or questions/day, so it's a good argument for HSE to graduate.